# Конфликт между плагинами на Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, popup, contact-form7

Сайт "Wordpress" + "Woocommerce" + тема "Oxygen" (Все версии последние).

[Вот сайт](http://4545536354665.newsite29.beget.tech/product/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80-1/)

На сайте есть всплывающая форма (внизу слева "Заказать звонок") а так же есть в карточке товара всплывающая форма от кнопки "Заказать" (справа от изображения).

Обе формы работают на плагине "Contact Form 7", так же для маскировки телефона установлен дополнительный плагин "Contact Form 7 — Маска ввода телефонного номера".

Форма "Заказать звонок" всплывает с помощью плагина "Popup Maker".
Форма в товаре всплывает при помощи плагина "Art WooCommerce Order One Click" для учета атрибутов.

И когда все это подключено и настроено не открывается окно в карточке.

Если отключить один из плагинов:
"Contact Form 7 — Маска ввода телефонного номера" или "Popup Maker", то форма начинает открываться.

Все эти плагины ооочень нужны, возможно есть решение как объединить хотя бы пару из них, например: плагин "Contact Form 7 — Маска ввода телефонного номера" перенести в основной плагин "Contact Form 7"

В консоли пишет ошибку:
[image: скриншот]

Comment: Возможность только одна - научиться программировать и выкинуть половину из названных плагинов.

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось!
в плагине "Art WooCommerce Order One Click" в файле awooc-scripts.js

начиная с о 133 строки и до 139 меняем это

```js
$this.mask(data_mask);

if (data_mask.indexOf('*') == -1 && data_mask.indexOf('a') == -1) {
$this.attr({
'inputmode': 'numeric'
});
}
```

на вот это

```js
try{
$this.mask(data_mask);

if (data_mask.indexOf('*') == -1 && data_mask.indexOf('a') == -1) {
$this.attr({
'inputmode': 'numeric'
});
}
} catch (e){console.log(e)}
```

и всё начинает работать!

Comment: Это конечно, здорово, что вы сами нашли решение проблемы. Но как вы теперь будете обновлять плагины? А если новая версия будет содержать обновления безопасности? Поэтому плагины править не следует, ав вносить изменения в их функционал только через хуки. А в вашем случае такой набор плагинов просто не нужен. Проще сделать всплывающее окно самому.